# Solr StandardTokenizer wild card an punctuation sing together in the same word strange behavior

Tags: solr, wildcard, punctuation

I have a problem with StandardTokenizer of Solr.

If i am searching for:

```
text_field:lastname
```

it will find something

If i am searching for:

```
text_field:last*ame
```

it will find soething

If I am searching for:

```
text_field:lastname;
```

But if I search for:

```
text_field:last*ame;
```

the search doesn't return anything. Why? StandardTokenizer shouldn't strip the punctuation sign from the end of the word? Basically if I use a wild card and a punctuation sign in a  word the punctuation sign is not striped anymore. There is a way to strip out punctuation signs even if we use wildcards?

Answer (score 1):

Solr does not perform any analysis on the query when you're doing wildcard queries. The term will just be used to do a wild card match against the tokens stored for the field. `StandardTokenizer` will split on word boundaries, and the `;` will be considered a boundary - which will mean that the tokens indexed does not contain `;`, but the query will.

You probably want to remove the `;` in your query layer.

[Here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultitermQueryAnalysis) is the link to the SOLR documentation that further explains why wildcard and other multiterm queries don't undergo analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It clarified things. But there is an easy way to strip the punctuation signs in combination with wildcards in Solr (maybe putting something in configuration), other than parsing the string and strip them?